# Discord bot to remove a line from a text file

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot that reads and writes to a text file. I type:

`+add <url>` and it will add a URL to a new line in the text file.

I need `+remove <url>` to remove a URL that matches it in that same text file.

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, args):
  url = args.lower() + '\n'

  with open('text.txt', 'a') as url_file:
    url_file.write(url)

@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx, args):
  url = args.lower() + '\n'

  with open("text.txt", 'r') as url_file:
    urls = url_file.readlines()

  replacement_urls = [url for url in urls if url != x]

  with open('text.txt', 'w') as url_file:
    url_file.truncate()
    url_file.write(''.join(replacement_urls))
```

+add works perfectly fine but when I run the remove command I get the error

`replacement_urls = [url for url in urls if url != x] NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You named the input url `url`, but in your list comprehension you re-assign `url` to each element of `urls`.

```py
replacement_urls = [x for x in urls if x != url]
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried this and got the following `replacement_urls = [x for x in urls if x != url]
NameError: name 'url' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception`